# HAVING COUNT receiving other COUNT value

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, having

I'm working with a select in two different tables that should be match by group reference id, like:
*Table 1 and table 2*:

```
+-----+-----+------------+   +-----+------+
| gid | tid | created    |   | gid | nid  |
+-----+-----+------------+   +-----+------+
|   0 | 816 | 1480002041 |   |   0 | 1123 |
|   1 | 731 | 1480003932 |   |   0 | 1124 |
|   1 | 736 | 1480003932 |   |   1 | 1125 |
|   2 | 746 | 1480003932 |   |   1 | 1126 |
+-----+-----+------------+   |   1 | 1123 |
                             |   2 | 1124 |
                             |   1 | 1129 |
                             +-----+------+
```

I need to get `nid` values from *table 2* that have a exactly group match with the group on *table 1*. The reference to search in *table 1* is `tid`.
I believe that the SQL would be something like that:

```
SELECT  t1.nid
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  gid 
    FROM    table2 
    WHERE   tid IN (731, 736, 746, 751)
    GROUP   BY gid
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT tid) = 4
) t2 ON t1.gid = t2.gid;
```

But how can I get the exactly `count` to replace hard coded `number 4`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.nid
  FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
  ON t1.gid = t2.gid;
WHERE t2.tid IN (731, 736, 746, 751)
  GROUP BY t2.gid
```

Comment: Thanks Roman Che, but doesn't work as expected. 
The results shouldn't return anything when `tid` values not match with `gid` count on second table